# Grafana - How to get the metrics that are used in dashboards?

Tags: filter, prometheus, grafana, metrics, grafana-api

Is there a way to get a list of all metrics that are being used in all of the active dashboards in my Grafana?

My team is evaluating the Grafana Cloud product, and since its pricing is based on the amount of active-series/data-series that are being sent to the server, we need a way to filter out unnecessary metrics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up developing this tool - https://github.com/unfor19/frigga